# How do I create a (Type, ID) (aka 'polymorphic')- foreign key column in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, rdbms

In Ruby-on-Rails, this is called a "polymorphic association."

I have several `Commentable` things in my application, the tables for each are below:

```
Post
id | title | text | author (FK:Person.id) | ...

Person
id | name | ...

Photo
id | title | owner (FK:Person.id) | path | ...
```

I'd like to add a `Comments` table as follows:

```
Comments
id | commentable_type | commentable_id | text | author (FK:Person.id)
```

I understand that I lose the database's referential integrity this way, but the only other option is to have multiple `Comments` tables: `PostComments`, `PersonComments`, `PhotoComments`, ...

**And now for the question:**

How can I build a form that will grok how to do the lookup, first by getting the table name from `Comments.commentable_type` and then the id from `Comments.commentable_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This technique is known colloquially in the SQL world as 'subclassing'. For a worked example (SQL Server syntax but is easily adapted for MS Access), see [David Porta's blog.](http://web.archive.org/web/20100309034643/http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/01/08/Distributed-Keys-and-Disjoint-Subtypes.aspx).

In your scenario, the data items common to all comments would be in your Comments table; anything specific to each type would be in specialized tables such as PhotoComments, etc. Note the FK should be the two-column compound of the ID plus the type, something which is often overlooked but is essential to referential integrity here e.g. you don’t want something typed as a photo comment appearing in the PersonComments table.

Comment: So how do you do the form for that?  That is, what's a good UI approach?

Answer (score 0):

I believe many people make meta-tables for that sort of thing. Pretty much exactly as you described it.